# Create new pull request default branch in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

When I create a new pull request in Visual Studio the target branch is not set to develop.  In the bitbucket settings online, develop is the default branch.  Where do I set this in Visual Studio 2017?  It always defaults to this random branch

[image]